# How can i set up email alerts for disk failures on a windows server 2012 box?

Tags: windows-server-2012, alerting

I have a windows 2012 server with 3 storage spaces set up, each containing a mirrored pair of 2TB drives.

What is the best way to set up alerting so that i receive an alert when a physical disk fails?

Ideally i would like these alerts to be sent via email to a pre-defined address.

The current server set up is as follows:

- Intel Core i7 2600k 3.4GHz Socket 1155 8MB Cache
- Asrock H77 PRO4/MVP Socket 1155 VGA DVI HDMI 7.1 Channel Audio ATX Motherboard
- 16GB RAM
- 1 x 60GB SSD (OS)
- 6 x 2TB SATA III 7200 HDD (DATA)

Comment: What hardware is this server made up of?

Comment: I have added the server specs to the question above.

Comment: THis is a custom build? Not a vendor? ALso RAID card? or no RAID card?

Comment: yes custom build, no raid card. Just using windows storage spaces with disk mirroring

Comment: why not attach a task to an eventlog entry.

Comment: You're going to regret buying these low-end components.

Answer (score 2):

I would set up a simple Nagios installation on another box on your network.  It can be put on a small desktop computer running Ubuntu if no additional server hardware is available.  Nagios can be configured to monitor just about anything.